# Customize color of tags in streamlit

Tags: html, css, streamlit

I am new to streamlit and trying to create an application which includes multiple tags object. The tags have a preset color set to red. I would like to have different color set for each tags element I have. For eg., I want to show tags under platform in blue and the tags under amount in purple.

[image]

I have tried to create a style.css file and open it within my main file but it doesn't seem to get applied

```
div.element-container css-3u772n e1tzin5v2 {
   background-color : #50C878;
}

with open('style.css') as f:
   st.markdown(f'<style>{f.read()}</style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

col7, col8= st.columns([2.5, 2.5])
with col7:
   platform = st_tags(
         value= ["Carousell"],
         maxtags=3,
         suggestions=["Carousell"],
         label="Platform",
      )
```

Appreciate some guidance on how to work with CSS style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using `st.multiselect` and injecting custom css on the page. If you know the options and they don't overlap between platforms and amounts, you can create a rule for each of them like I did. It checks if the `span` has a span child with the correct `title` and it colors the parent if so.

```py
import streamlit as st

possible_platforms = ["Carousell", "Foo", "Bar"]
possible_amounts = [">$300", "<=$300"]

for pfm in possible_platforms:
    st.markdown(
        f"""
    <style>
    span[data-baseweb="tag"]:has(span[title="{pfm}"]) {{
    background-color: blue !important;
    }}
    </style>
    """,
        unsafe_allow_html=True,
    )

for amount in possible_amounts:
    st.markdown(
        f"""
    <style>
    span[data-baseweb="tag"]:has(span[title="{amount}"]) {{
    background-color: purple !important;
    }}
    </style>
    """,
        unsafe_allow_html=True,
    )

st.markdown("Report Category Specific Parameters")

st.multiselect("Platform", possible_platforms)
st.multiselect("Amount", possible_amounts)
```

[image: Platforms in Blue and amounts in purple]

---

**Note**: The `has` pseudo-class is supported on every browser [except Firefox](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

Comment: Thanks so much :) this solutions works for my case.